# How to Ordered By the # of a column selected in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have the following SQL Stored Proc Query

```
@colindex int

SELECT
   di.folio,
   di.name,
   di.region,
   di.amount
FROM datainfo di
WHERE di.isactive = 1
ORDER BY .....@colindex 'where colindex is the index of the column returned
```

Example:

if @colindex = 1 then the column that I want to order by is "folio" column.

if @colindex = 4 then the column that I want to order by is "amount" column.

Any clue on how to deal with this in SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@colindex int

SELECT
   di.folio,
   di.name,
   di.region,
   di.amount
FROM datainfo di
WHERE di.isactive = 1
ORDER BY case @colindex  when 1 then di.folio when 4 then di.amount end
```

Comment: Is is possible also to have a @ordertype (asc or desc) and add that to the query?

Comment: any clue on how to do that? Appreciate so much your help!

Comment: case @ordertype when 'A' then Asc when 'D' then Desc end   you need to pass to variable with values either  'A' or 'D'.

Comment: that doesn't work - you have to do separate case clauses, like ORDER BY case when @typ = 'A' then <your condition> else NULL end ASC, <your condition DESC, ...

Comment: OR...  if the condition is numeric, you could ORDER BY <your condition> * case when @typ = 'A' then 1 else -1 end

Comment: I just ended concatenating sortindex column and sortdirection like this: SET sort = CONVERT(varchar,sortedindex) + ' ' + sorteddir

And then ORDER BY
  case WHEN sort = '0 ASC' OR sort= '1 ASC' Then [date] ELSE null END ASC,
  case WHEN sort = '0 DESC' OR sort= '1 DESC' Then [date] ELSE null END DESC, etc.......

Answer (score 3):

```
order by case @colindex when 1 then folio when 2 then ... end
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds, damn you carriage returns :P

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would be very fast but you could add:

```
ORDER BY CASE @colindex 
             WHEN 1 THEN [MyColumn1]
             WHEN 2 THEN [MyColumn2]
             WHEN 3 THEN [MyColumn3]
             WHEN 4 THEN [MyColumn4]
         END
```

To add asc/desc:

```
ORDER BY CASE @sortorder
    WHEN 'ASC' THEN
        CASE @colindex 
            WHEN 1 THEN [MyColumn1]
            WHEN 2 THEN [MyColumn2]
            WHEN 3 THEN [MyColumn3]
            WHEN 4 THEN [MyColumn4]
         END
    END,
    CASE @sortorder
        WHEN 'DES' THEN
        CASE @colindex 
            WHEN 1 THEN [MyColumn1]
            WHEN 2 THEN [MyColumn2]
            WHEN 3 THEN [MyColumn3]
            WHEN 4 THEN [MyColumn4]
         END
    END DESC
```

To explain, the two orders will both apply but the first will be constantly `NULL` when the `@sortorder` variable is 'ASC'.

Comment: why downvoted? there are 3 other people that suggested this same thing AFTER this guy

Comment: @Артём Царионов First of all, there are only two other answers here, and secondly, bwperrin answered this question first. If you going to get narky, get your facts straight.

Comment: Is is possible also to have a @ordertype (asc or desc) and add that to the query? –